# How to set default save location

Tags: default, navigation, location

With windows if you save a new file from a certain application, it will usually remember the folder you saved it so the next time you save a new file from that app it will automatically open that folder.

With Ubuntu it's been sort of frustrating that every time I try to save a file from, for example IDLE, I have to navigate to `Home/Documents/Programming/Python/` to save it where I want. Some applications you can set save paths, but not all of them. Is there a way to set up Ubuntu so that when I ctrl-s from the same application, it will remember the previous folder I saved from?

Or at least set up the default location to Documents, to save myself a couple of steps and automatically go to a folder I'm more likely to want to save files in?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great question! I don't think plain Ubuntu does this, though.

Comment: That is application specific. If the app remembers the last folder used.

Comment: this can't be application specific as chrome on windows remembers the previous download location and chrome on ubuntu does not. Within Chrome settings there are only two download settings. 
1. Default Download Folder 
2. Ask for location before saving